# Solidworks API C# / VB.net set Enum property

Tags: c#, solidworks

The [Solidworks eDrawings API](http://help.solidworks.com/2019/english/api/emodelapi/eDrawings.Interop.EModelViewControl~eDrawings.Interop.EModelViewControl.IEModelViewControl~EnableFeature.html) lists the following

**EnableFeature Property (IEModelViewControl)**

**Visual Basic (Usage)**

```
 Dim instance As IEModelViewControl
 Dim feature As EMVEnableFeatures
 Dim value As System.Boolean

 instance.EnableFeature(feature) = value

 value = instance.EnableFeature(feature)
```

Solidworks provides an "example" solution (C#.NET) for which the following is the control

```
this.eDrawingControl1 = new eDrawingHostControl.eDrawingControl();
```

Looking into the eDrawingHost.eDrawingControl namespace we can see

```
 public EModelViewControl eDrawingControlWrapper { get; }
```

So I would think

```
eDrawingControl1.eDrawingControlWrapper.EnableFeature(feature) = true;
```

would work, but instead I get

> Non-invocable member 'IEModelViewControl.EnableFeature[EMVEnableFeatures]' cannot be used like a method.

As proof the instance is OK and working properly, something like

```
eDrawingControl1.eDrawingControlWrapper.Save(@"filePath", false,"");
```

works perfectly fine.

Am I misunderstanding the C# syntax for setting such a (enum) property?

Comment: VB.Net lets you pass parameters to properties but c# does not.

Comment: The error indicates that you have a property with no parameter like : .EnableFeature = true;  The property is applied to an instance of an object.  The save method you have an instance : eDrawingControl1.eDrawingControlWrapper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like their wrapper is using a named indexer, something you can't do in C#. You can however consume it from C#:

```
eDrawingControl1.eDrawingControlWrapper.EnableFeature[feature] = true;
```

Comment: Thanks! I swore I tried this but whatever I did last time wasn't this, apparently.